# Mysql Removing last 2 char from string if char matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have got some improper data with some of my rows due to which I am not able to search exactly.

I have values under my category_name column like below:

```
category_name

interior--
exterior
interior
```

due to `--` at the  end of some category names I am not able to get exact counts of a particular category

I am using below query

```
select count(id) from designs where category_name='interior'
```

how to ignore `--` while matching in where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Trim**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) the trailing `--` from values using TRIM() function like below:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM designs WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '--' FROM category_name)='interior'
```

Comment: Would it trim just two `-`s at the end or any even number of trailing `-`s?

Answer (score 0):

OR you can use LIKE to search only for interior. I guess you need to do that.

```
select count(id) from designs where category_name LIKE 'interior'
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Can't use like because I have other similar categories too like 'interior decorator' so count will not  be correct

Answer (score 0):

To find the string "--" anywhere in the field and also remove leading and trailing whitespace, this would work:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM designs WHERE TRIM(REPLACE(category_name, '--', ''))='interior'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an index on category_name, this will be much more efficient than applying a function to every row, since it will be able to utilize the index:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM designs WHERE category_name IN ('interior', 'interior--')
```